# convergence of integrals

Tags: measure-theory

if $f$ is integrable, i wish to show

$\frac{n}{2} \int_{-1/n}^{1/n} (f(x+y) - f(x))dy \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty $

this looks to be very intuitive, but im having trouble proving it formally. any tips?

EDIT: added the n infront of the integral, thanks Jonas

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense as stated.  Do you mean $n\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}f(x+y)dy\to 2f(x)$?  This will not hold in general, but you may want to look at Lebesgue points. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point

Comment: You have not fixed the question.  You still probably want an $n$ in front of the integral.  If this is really what you want to ask, then the answer is yes, because $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}f(x)dy\to0$ (trivially) and $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}f(x+y)dy\to0$ (because $f$ is integrable, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if the measure of $A$ is less than $\delta$ then $|\int_A f|<\epsilon$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plausible interpretation of the question is that you're asking whether $\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}f(x+y)dy$ is asymptotically equivalent to $\frac{2}{n}f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$, which amounts to the same as asking whether $\frac{n}{2}\int_{-1/n}^{1/n}f(x+y)dy\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$.  If $f$ is locally integrable, then this holds almost everywhere by [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).  You could not hope for more than this, because changing the value of $f$ at $x$ (or on any set of measure $0$) will not affect the integrals.

Edit: Since I first posted, the question was edited to what I answered.